# Liaison on « tellement »

Tags: liaisons

Je viens de regarder une vidéo où une locutrice native du Canada qui dit « je suis tellement /z/ heureuse ». Je ne peux pas inclure un lien vers la vidéo entière mais en voici un extrait :

> « [Je suis tellement heureuse qu'il ait<sup>1</sup> enfin commencé à faire beau dehors.](https://unfamiliarplace.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/tellement-zheureuse.mp3) »

Il semble s'agir d'une « liaison fantôme »... C'est le même phénomène qui se produit par exemple dans « donne-moi-z'en » ?

Au Canada est-ce que c'est plutôt normal d'insérer un /z/ de liaison ici aussi ? Y a-t-il une catégorie de mots pour laquelle je peux m'assurer de pouvoir faire cette « liaison fantôme » ou est-ce que c'est un peu au gré du locuteur ?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Je crois avoir bien transcrit ce mot. Je crois entendre la diphtonguaison que subit souvent cette voyelle au Canada et je trouve que nous avons tendance à employer le subjonctif même pour ce fait réel qui exigerait l'indicatif dans d'autres variétés du français...</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

L'extrait contient bien la phrase:

> *Je suis tellement "z'heureuse" qu'il ait enfin commencé à faire beau dehors.*

C'est effectivement un cas très similaire à celui de la paire *donnes-en* / *donne-moi z'en*.

Cette liaison est ce qu'on appelle un [velours](https://l-express.ca/des-liaisons-de-velours-et-de-cuir/). Elle est probablement due au fait que sans l'adverbe *tellement*, elle aurait pu être réalisée :

> *Je suis‿heureuse.*

Le *S* de la liaison aura été transféré de la fin du mot précédent au début du mot suivant, et a résisté à l'insertion d'un nouveau mot à l'emplacement de la liaison.

Une autre explication peut être une conséquence de la fréquence élevée de liaison devant *heureuse*, comme dans *très heureuse* qui tend à pérenniser la présence d'un /z/ à cet endroit.

On entend ce type de liaison plus souvent au pluriel, où ce *S* initial a tendance à se répandre comme préfixe marqueur du pluriel:

> *Ils sont z‿heureux.* /ilsɔ̃zøʁø/

Le subjonctif est bien le temps attendu ici car ce n'est pas un fait qui est rapporté, mais un sentiment sur ce fait.

> *Je suis heureux qu'il a réussi.* est rejeté et stigmatisé par la norme.

La même norme [rejette](http://academie-francaise.fr/donne-moi-le) l'expression *donne-moi-z'en*, non pas tellement pour la liaison qui s'impose ici (liaison euphonique, que l'on rend par un *s* dans *donnes-en*), mais pour le pronom utilisé *moi* alors que *me* est attendu<sup>1</sup>.

La forme enseignée est donc:

> *Donne-m'en.*

On entend cependant souvent:

> *Donne moi-z'en.* qui est même [la forme habituelle](https://linguistech.ca/Capsule+linguistique+-+Donne+m+en) au Canada francophone.

et aussi:

> *Donnes-en moi.*

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Ce *me* peut surprendre car *donne-moi* est correct et *donne-me* rejeté et inutilisé sauf dans *refait-le-me-le*...</sub>

Comment: Pas sûr que ce soit une liaison à distance ici, j'ai fréquemment des /z/ entre ce genre d'adverbe et des adjectifs, quel que soit le contexte précédent (par ex. j'ai pas trouvé ça trop/si/tellement-z-intéressant). C'est probablement juste dû à la fréquence de très dans ce genre de constructions (+ assez, je suppose), qui répand sa consonne de liaison aux autres adverbes par analogie

Comment: @Eauquidort Oui, c'est aussi possible. Je vais remplacer *certainement* par *probablement*. On ne peut pas savoir ce qui a motivé ce /z/ dans ce cas précis.

Comment: Interesting! No less for the L'express article alone (whatever one may think of its stance) than for the rest. I would love to see additional theories, but the two proposed make sense. I wondered about liaison à distance as well, but I'm open to the spontaneous/purely euphonic explanation too (after all, where would it be borrowed from in *donne-moi-z'en*?). And thanks for the note on the subjonctif; I remembered but couldn't find a thread where there was a similar Canadian sentence with *ait* that a Hexagonian said should be indicative, but I guess it wasn't analogous to this one.

Comment: About *donne-moi-z'en*: the singular second person imperative *donne* takes an extra *s* to sustain that liaison, e.g. : *donnes-en à ton frère*.

Comment: @jlliagre Oh, true, of course.